# UIWebView in iOS app cannot see JavaScript when loaded through File Sharing

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, file-sharing

In my iOS app, I have a way for the User to install a zip file through iTunes/Apps Tab/File sharing.  The zip file contains HTML/CSS/JavaScript.  The app unzips the file and index.html file is loaded in a UIWebView.  This works fine.

I know when you add JavaScript files along with HTML/CSS files into the Resources folder in XCode, before compiling you need to move the JavaScript files from the Compile Resources folder into the Copy Bundle Resources folder or the HTML cannot find the JavaScript file.

For the resources that I am loading through iTunes File Sharing, it appears that the HTML files cannot find the JavaScript files.  What else do I need to do when adding the files through File Sharing in order for the HTML to use the JavaScript file?

TIA,
Linda

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the `baseURL` parameter of whichever UIWebView load method you're using to display the HTML content is being set incorrectly.  I would try setting `baseURL` to the file URL pointing to the folder containing the unzipped assets, perhaps using `NSBundle`'s `- (NSURL *)URLForResource:(NSString *)name withExtension:(NSString *)extension` method, or something similar.

Comment: The HTML and CSS are being displayed correctly. Only the JavaScript that the page points to is not being seen by the HTML.